# Mute an APK file

Tags: apk, mute

How to patch an APK file so that its permanently mute?

For example if I want to send a game to my friend but don't want him to hear its sound?

Can I edit permissions related to Audio?

Comment: most apps/games are developed with toggle switch to turn off the Game volume, from it's settings. Don't your game/app has this feature? And AFAIK you may not be able to edit App features once app is installed.

Comment: Yes but I want to force mute it

Comment: There is no audio permission, because (nothing personal) that would be ridiculous. Apps rely on queues to play audio e.g. Play track 1 when player hits start. In theory, if you removed all the sounds from the apk (or replace them) it will mute the app.

Comment: Why can't your friend opt for turning the speakers off when playing your game? That's rather easy.

Comment: What is your device information and os and are your rooted? And which app/game you are trying to mute?

Comment: Both devices are 4.3, Mine rooted but his not

Comment: I want a universal solution